# Docker - Unable to pull images - certificate issues?

Tags: docker

I have installed Ubuntu on Oracle VirtualBox on my Corporate Machine which is running Windows 7. On Ubuntu , I have the latest docker installed. I am behind corporate proxy. I guess, I have set up right HTTP_PROXY params.

However, when I try running a simple command , I get the below issue.

> tma0si3UBUNTU:~$ sudo docker run hello-world Unable to find image
>   'hello-world' locally Pulling repository hello-world af340544ed62:
>   Error pulling image (latest) from hello-world, endpoint:
>   https://registry-1.docker.io/v1/,x50af340544ed62:
>   Error pulling image (latest) from hello-world, x509: certificate signed by unknown authority 2015/09/10 10:26:37 Could not find repository on any of the indexed registries.

Any help ?

Comment: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/6474